# Heap Analysis - only first value of custom event properties is tracked

Tags: reactjs, analysis, heap-analytics, heap.io

```
export function useHeapAddEventCaseCode(caseData?: CaseEntity) {
  return useEffect(() => {
    if (caseData?.code) {
      // As a best practice, we recommend calling clearEventProperties before addEventProperties on every page
      window.heap.clearEventProperties() 
      window.heap.addEventProperties({ caseCode: caseData.code })
    }
  }, [caseData])
}
```

I'm using this effect on React SPA app in some page. Somehow it's only track first value, never see any other value even though I tried other case codes
[image]
heap array in console.log has other caseCode but none of those is sent to heap analysis or not appear
[image]

Comment: This is likely relevant: "_Note that this API may not work well with Single Page Applications, which have a tendency to change state in a way that impacts the timing of the cookie being sent to the API._" - from [the docs](https://developers.heap.io/reference/addeventproperties)

Comment: @RandyCasburn yep I saw that too but it's really weird that after a few days not using the web app, I open it with different case code but it does not track anything new.

Comment: That does seem odd, I'm certain you are clearing the cookies from that host - right?

Comment: hmm, does not clear anything. Other thing like addUserProperties, identify work fine. Also on heap dashboard there is many other default events working, unfortunately not this custom stuff